# know in Ionic which phone audio output the user is using (speakerphone, earphone, headset...)

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

I am developing an hybrid mobile app using Ionic.
I need to know which audio output is used by the user.

In the specific, I need to know which he's using during a phone call, even with my app on the background.

Is it possible?